# Populate SharePoint List from Data captured in web form

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

I am trying to gather project ideas in a Sharepoint List that users will fill out via a web form.  Does anyone know how to connect the two, so after the user clicks Submit, the data will appear in the SharePoint List?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Build a custom WebSite, that populates a SharePoint List? Which version of SharePoint? Have you had a look at the rest API (i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem )

Comment: I am using Project Online which I believe sits on top of SharePoint 2013.  I want users to fill out a form of project ideas (maybe 6-8 fields) and when the submit it, the data gets stored in a Sharepoint List I created called Ideas.

Answer (score 1):

By web form if you are referring to a .Net page, you could use CSOM to connect to your site and create a new list item. [MSDN article on CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)

Another great idea would be to use REST API if you cannot have managed code.

Research a bit and you will be able to make a choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your own page as a form, you could use the [REST-API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem) from the server. This would enable you to use a techical user to access SharePoint. REST-APIs are usable from any language (PHP, Java, etc.)

If you're hosting your own page as a form on an asp.net-enabled server you could also use [CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx). Again, this would enable you to use a techical user to access SharePoint.

You could also leverage the [REST-API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem) to be used in JavaScript on the client-side. Note however, that every user which than accesses your form needs to be a valid SharePoint-user to access the list.

You could of cause host your form in SharePoint and use [SP.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx) to access the List-data. If you'd do that (hosting in SharePoint) it would probably be better do directly use the NewForm.aspx.